# Java multi-thread programming - atomic operation

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrent-programming

I am on my way learning multi-thread programming with Java. Here is a confusion I got.

```
class Cache<K, V> {
private ConcurrentMap<K, V> cache;
private ConcurrentLinkedQueue<K> lru;

public Cache () {
    // initiate cache and lru
}

public put (K key, V value) {
    // some pre-processing
    synchronized (this) {
        cache.put(key, value);
        lru.add(key);
    }
    // some post-processing
}

}
```

Here is some very simple cache with a least recently used record (lru). Obviously I need to make these two operations atomic. Otherwise it's very likely the state of cache and lru would be different.

Now assume I want to have a timer task to clean the cache, say it will clean half the cache. My question is does my code above ensure these two operations (put cache and add lru) appear atomic to the clean task? Can I do something like below:

```
class CleanTask {
    Cache cache;   // the reference of Cache
    public void run () {
        // some pre-processing
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {   // Just suppose I need remove n element
            synchronized (XXX) {
                cache.getCache().remove(cache.getLru().poll());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And what should I put in XXX?

Thanks a lot!!!

Comment: Your LRU should not be part of the public contract of the class. And your clean method should probable be implemented by the cache itself, and not by an external task.

Comment: Unless you are implementing this as a learning exercise, you might want to have a look at the caches package in Google Guava http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/CachesExplained - even if it is a learning exercise, it might be worth having how the Guava folks have implemented things in any case.

Comment: @Perception What do you mean by "LRU should not be part of the public contract of the class"? My idea is that when the cache hits its capacity, it will initiate a thread to do the cleaning job, but at the same time, users should still be able to put things into the cache.

Comment: @msandiford Thank you! I am trying to learn from Guava.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> My question is does my code above ensure these two operations (put cache and add lru) appear atomic to the clean task?

yes (assuming cleaning task is in different thread)

> And what should I put in XXX?

the same cache object for example: `synchronized (cache) {` a the synchronization should happen on the same lock (object)

you can also explore other atomic classes in java if they could be useful in your case: [atomic package](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/package-summary.html)

Comment: `ReentrantReadWriteLock` might be worth considering also from `java.util.concurrent.locks` http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/package-summary.html

Answer (score 0):

In your case, you would synchronize on **cache** at XXX, however, I suggest you look at synchronizing the **put** and **getLru** methods as an alternative.